# How to fix Jetpack Compose theme using colors not in the theme/Color.kt file?

Tags: material-design, android-jetpack-compose

I set an original theme for an app. Did a bit of work then came back to change the theme. However, no matter what colors I change to, the old theme remains and now somehow it has even translated over to a test app that I created fresh.

[Image of Activitz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1QVy.png)

This was an Empty Compose Activity (Material3) that I added a Column and a button to. As you can see, the button is not the purple it would usually be. It is actually a blue that I used in the old theme of a completely different app (the app above).

The Color.kt file:

```
package com.phoenixredwolf.test.ui.theme

import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color

val Purple80 = Color(0xFFD0BCFF)
val PurpleGrey80 = Color(0xFFCCC2DC)
val Pink80 = Color(0xFFEFB8C8)

val Purple40 = Color(0xFF6650a4)
val PurpleGrey40 = Color(0xFF625b71)
val Pink40 = Color(0xFF7D5260)
```

The Theme.kt file:

```
package com.phoenixredwolf.test.ui.theme

import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Build
import androidx.compose.foundation.isSystemInDarkTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.darkColorScheme
import androidx.compose.material3.dynamicDarkColorScheme
import androidx.compose.material3.dynamicLightColorScheme
import androidx.compose.material3.lightColorScheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.SideEffect
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.toArgb
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalView
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat

private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    primary = Purple80,
    secondary = PurpleGrey80,
    tertiary = Pink80
)

private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    primary = Purple40,
    secondary = PurpleGrey40,
    tertiary = Pink40,
    surface = Purple40

    /* Other default colors to override
    background = Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
    surface = Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
    onPrimary = Color.White,
    onSecondary = Color.White,
    onTertiary = Color.White,
    onBackground = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    onSurface = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    */
)

@Composable
fun TestTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }
        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            (view.context as Activity).window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(view)?.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

The MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.phoenixredwolf.test

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.phoenixredwolf.test.ui.theme.TestTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TestTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
        Text(text = "Hello $name!")
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Text(text = "button")
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    TestTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

I've tried several times changing the color. I am able to change the button color programatically using ButtonDefaults.buttonColors. However it seems that even though the primary color is defined in the Theme.kt file as Purple80, when I set button color programmatically to MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary, it gets the blue color which isn't defined anywhere. I'm at a loss at this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is tricky answer So let me explain.

Whenever you will use device below android level 12 it will run as a preview but If you are trying to use device Above android 12+ you have change one in '**Theme.kt**' file.

Change `dynamicColor: Boolean = true` to `dynamicColor: Boolean = false`

Now you will get output same as compose preview.

Comment: the issue primary color still not override from color.kt i still get purple color for primary

Comment: did change colors code and changes on theme.kt

Comment: @BlackBlind can you provide more explanation on this, please? I had a different issue with the Jetpack Compose Preview not working, but the moment I made the change you suggested it started working. I'd like to understand why your suggestion works, if you can provide more details please.

Comment: @Ugo It is so simple android 13 or 14 (I am not sure in version) is using dynamic color by default